# Why does the trajectory return a domain which appears to "rotate" around the origin point (0, 0)?

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to use the trajectory formula in a video game I am designing to calculate the parabola a fishing bobber follows as it fly's through the air.

The formula I am using is as follows:
[The formula I am using.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6j8vn.png)

*variable A refers to the angle in degrees.*

*variable X refers to the position on the X axis*

---

What I've found is that when I supply a values such as 45 degrees I will get a parabola that essentially starts at 0,0 and ends on a positive X value. While a value such as 15 will travel in the opposite direction.

**How do I make it so all of the returned parabola's start at X = 0 and end at a positive X value?**

**Also why does the formula work in the way I've laid out?**

Examples:

[When A = 45 degrees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyEbz.png)
*A = 45 degrees*

[When A = 15 degrees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuQt0.png)
*A = 15 degrees*

Comment: You forgot to make sure the trig functions are using degrees instead of radians. I tried plotting your equation using $a = 15$ RADIANS, and it looks like the picture you posted where one of the $x$-intercepts is negative (close to $-0.1$).

Comment: Thank you so much @Nick